# How to perform a bulk update of documents with multiple filters in MongoDB 3 with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, filter, driver, bulk

I want to make a Bulk Update like this:

```
        List<WriteModel<Document>> writes = new ArrayList<WriteModel<Document>>();
    writes.add(
            new UpdateOneModel<Document>(
                    new Document("car", "Ferrari"), // filter
                    new Document("$set", new Document("color", "Black")) // update
            )
    );
```

But I want to input more than one filter. I thought it would be something like this:

```
        List<WriteModel<Document>> writes = new ArrayList<WriteModel<Document>>();
    writes.add(
            new UpdateOneModel<Document>(
                    new Document(and(eq("car", "Ferrari"), eq("color", "Red"), // filter
                    new Document("$set", new Document("color", "Black")) // update
            )
    );
```

But it obviously doesn't work, and I can't find it anywhere. Does anyone know if there is any way to do it? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use append to add the other keys:

```
List<WriteModel<Document>> writes = new ArrayList<WriteModel<Document>>();
writes.add(
    new UpdateOneModel<Document>(
        new Document("car", "Ferrari").append("color", "Red"), // filter
        new Document("$set", new Document("color", "Black")) // update
    )
);
```